# How can I clamp the voltage precisely from the back EMF of a brushed DC motor?

Tags: back-emf, emf, brushed-dc-motor, clamp

I am using DRV8412DDWR in a medical product, where we are driving two DC motors (graphite brushed) bidirectional using PWM.

In our application, we have to suddenly stop the motor.  When we do that, we are seeing a back EMF current of ~1 ampere due to which the main power supply voltage rises. The PSU unit detects that as overvoltage and shuts down.

To address this, I am planning to have a Schottky diode, bulk capacitor and a 36V Zener. Is that the best option, or is there any other easy and better solution?

I want to restrict the voltage raise not more than 1V ( not >37V,) but the Zener regulation is not that accurate. I didn't get any useful feedback from TI (the drive IC representative.)

I am attaching the waveform I captured, circuit logic and the proposed changes.

[image]

[image]

Comment: Data sheet DRV8412DDWR Chapt. 9.1 (page 24) recommends adding a *bulk capacitor* to PVDD. Example circuits show 1000uf. This capacitor belongs close to the PVDD pin, and the local GND pin. If PVDD rises due to motor back-EMF, capacitance may be insufficient.

Comment: This is not back EMF, it is flyback from the motor's inductance. Back EMF wold only exceed the PSU if the load started driving the motor faster than its rated speed at 36V.

Answer (score 7):

If the sole purpose is to avoid triggering the PSU's over-volt shutdown, then you can use the PSU as your voltage reference.

[image: schematic]

<sup>[simulate this circuit](/plugins/schematics?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2forEwM.png) – Schematic created using [CircuitLab](https://www.circuitlab.com/)</sup>

As the load voltage rises above the PSU voltage, the PNP will turn on, and clamp its rise.

R2 is optional, it helps reduce the heating in the transistor. Keep it small enough that the reverse current is still clamped. R1 is nominal, but might be a bit high for a low beta Q1. It's possible the base current through R1 raises the voltage of the PSU if there is no other load on it, so make sure the PSU has sufficient load to provide Q1's base current. You could replace Q1 by a darlington, or even a super-alpha pair if you want to keep the excess voltage below 1 V.

Comment: Great. Thanks Neil. Did you get a chance to simulate this?..it seems not working for me..

Comment: @NiceGuy No need to model it, the concept obviously works, even if the 1k base resistor is too high to supply enough base current to a low beta PNP you happen to have chosen and limit the voltage rise to 1 v or whatever your specifiication is. I've added a few obvious caveats to the answer.

Answer (score 3):

If you want the overvoltage detection to happen automatically, and be quite accurate, you need to look into implementing it with a comparator and a precise voltage reference (e.g. divide PSU voltage to around 2.45V and use a 1% 2.5V voltage reference). This could switch in some resistive load to absorb the peak.

If the stopping current spike is well characterized and consistent (i.e. the motor is not attached to something that may have varied mechanical load or inertia) you can ditch the comparator/reference and leave just the load, controlled by your main MCU:

[image: schematic]

<sup>[simulate this circuit](/plugins/schematics?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2fi32es.png) – Schematic created using [CircuitLab](https://www.circuitlab.com/)</sup>

I.e., when you want to stop:

- command the motor to stop
- turn on M1
- wait for some time (~30ms if I'm reading your scope trace right)
- turn off M1

For R1 in theory you need 40W power resistor, but since it would be on for a very short amount of time, you get by with 5 or 10watt one.

Answer (score 3):

> In our application, we have to suddenly stop the motor.

> seeing a back EMF current of ~1 ampere

As mentioned in the comments, this is not back emf. The motor is spinning under load with a crrent of \$\approx 1A\$. The motor inductance carries the current. When the motor is stopped the inductor the voltage will increase across the inductor proportional to the rate of decline of the current.

> want to restrict the voltage raise not more than 1V ( not
> >37V,)

If the motor is supposed to stop suddenly (perhaps for safety reasons), then the higher the voltage the faster it stops. This current is actualy maintaining the torque that keeps the motor spinning. I think it is desirable to have the torque, and therefore the current, decrease as quickly as possible.

So the voltage raise should be higher than lower. The full bridge that you are using will handle up to 70V on PVDD.

The application note in the [data sheet](https://www.ti.com/lit/ds/symlink/drv8412.pdf?ts=1683427255419&ref_url=https%253A%252F%252Fwww.ti.com%252Fproduct%252FDRV8412) suggests a \$1000\mu F\$ capacitor on PVDD. I would parallel that with some ceramics. The capacitor in your proposed change should be already installed. If it  isn't, then you should check the design with the datsheet reference designs.

> I am planning to have a Schottky diode, bulk capacitor and a 36V Zener. Is that the best option, or is there any other easy and better solution?

The best option depends on the application. Only you can decide that.

My long answer is prompted by the need to stop suddenly.

1. The Schottky diode in series with the PSU is appropriate.
2. The bulk capacitoris good, but there should be one there already. Keep the distance the current has to travel as short as possible. The current leaving the motor's inductor must have a clear return path to its other end. Since the power supply cannot sink reversecurrent then that pathis interrupted. The diode in series makes the bulk capacitor all the more necessary to provide that path.
3. Let the voltage rise as high as is practicle. Other pins on the chip cannot take voltages that the PVDD pins can. If you want the motor to stop suddenly then this is important. I don't think the Zener diode is necessary. It may be required to protect elements on the driver board or if PVDD approaches 70V. The series diode will protect the power supply. I would prefer to increase the bulk capacitance.

So in the end I hope that I have given you some information to help you decide. Understand what happens when a motor is forced to stop. Be certain toknow the difference between back-emf and inductive kick.

There is an error your proposed diagram. The red line shows the current continueing to the PSU. It doesn't. It retirns to the motor inductor through ground and the drive chip. I have attached a correction below.

The red line is wrong. The blue line is correct.

[image]